# Weierestrass's theorem for manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, weierstrass-approximation

In this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356253/non-density-of-continuous-functions-to-interior-in-set-of-all-continuous-functio) the answer states that *"by Weierstrass' approximation theorem,
Annie's question is equivalent to: when is $C^\infty(M,N')$ not $C^0$-dense
in $C^\infty(M,N)$"*

However, what is Weirestrass' approximation theorem for manifolds?  Does anyone have a reference?

Comment: What post? Maybe a link?

Comment: My mistake.  Thanks for pointing out that key detail...